# Changing of iMessage account

Tags: ipad, messages, apple-id

I want to make a new iMessage account and stop using my old Apple ID for messaging. I need to know if it will change my apple id from which I download my apps?

Comment: Imessage is associated with your apple id. How do you want to change it?

Comment: I want to make a new account on iMessage.

Answer (score 2):

You can have separate accounts for iMessage and iTunes purchases. Having a different iMessage account will not affect your purchased apps.

To change the iMessage account, go to Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive. Tap on your current account name to change it.

For iTunes purchases, your account is specified at Settings -> iTunes & App Store.

You can even have a separate iCloud account.

The only caveat with doing this is that when setting up a new device, you need to be sure to enter these accounts separately. If you follow the default setup flow, both Messages and iTunes will use the same account (but you can change it as outlined above.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by new account? If you would like to change the email people can reach you at, it's easy to do. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.imore.com/how-add-additional-apple-ids-imessage). You can also remove the old email too, in Settings>Messages>Send&Receive .

That would provide the same effect as creating a new account, with out affecting the email you use to download apps.

Comment: I don't want to change my email. Ok here is an example. If my current email to download my apps is exaple@hotmail.com. And I want to log in my imessage from a different email id known as fatimasheikh@hotmail.com, will my first email I'd change. Because to log in iMessage you need an apple id. And to download your apps you need an apple id too. So if I change my iMessage apple id, will it change my download app id too?

Comment: Oh, is that the question? No, the app Apple ID is separate from the iMessage Apple ID.